# How can we navigation new view using SwiftUI List with navigation Link?

Tags: list, swiftui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7om4f.png)
Please give me suggestion is this best way for navigation multiple items or how to get index and put condition on tap of row ?

Comment: I would use the new NavigationStack. It's much easier to use and also has new feature which allows you to navigate better.

Comment: Okay. I have to check NavigationStack.